# Bind function made jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I created a function enterkey that detect when you click the button enter.
The problem is that i have to bind this function for add a comment inside a input created by jquery. How can i do that? Thank you! :)

```
$.fn.enterKey = function (fnc) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keypress(function (ev) {
            var keycode = (ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : ev.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                fnc.call(this, ev);
            }
        })
    })
}

var add_comment = { // add comment
    urlRemove : CI_ROOT + 'add_comment/',
    run : function() {
        add_comment.share('.comment');
    },
    share : function(obj) {
        $(obj).enterKey(function() { // I have to bind this function
            var comment = $(this);
            if (comment.val() != "") {
                     $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:  add_comment.urlRemove,
                        data: "text=" + comment.val() + "&post_id=" + comment.attr('id'),
                        success: function(html) {
                            comment.val('');
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert('Error on ajax call');
                        }
                    }); 

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: `(ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : ev.which)` depending your jq version but this has been normalized, you should just use `ev.which`

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: for me your code is working fine.. check here: http://jsfiddle.net/dJRAf/

Comment: Yes, work fine. But example if i load by ajax the input text obviusly doesn't work because is not binded.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you're really looking for event delegation ?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a input printed by call ajax and possibility to send the message from that input text. I think that the problem is because that function doesn't have the bind. I tried to bind the function that i made but without result. Thank you